# Java: accessing a non-static field in an anonymous class in a static context

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

Consider the following class:

```
public class DataStructure {
    
    // Create an array
    private final static int SIZE = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

    public DataStructure() {
        // fill the array with ascending integer values
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void print(DataStructureIterator iter) {
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iter.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator<Integer> { } 

    // Inner class implements the DataStructureIterator interface,
    // which extends the Iterator<Integer> interface
    
    private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator {
        
        // Start stepping through the array from the beginning
        private int nextIndex = 0;
        
        public boolean hasNext() {
            
            // Check if the current element is the last in the array
            return (nextIndex <= SIZE - 1);
        }        
        
        public Integer next() {
            
            // Record a value of an even index of the array
            Integer retValue = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfInts[nextIndex]);
            
            // Get the next even element
            nextIndex += 2;
            return retValue;
        }

    }
    
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        
        // Fill the array with integer values and print out only
        // values of even indices
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
    
        ds.print(
            new DataStructure.DataStructureIterator() {
                private int nextIndex = 1;
                public boolean hasNext() { 
                    return (nextIndex <= ds.size() - 1);
                }
                public Integer next() {
                    //int retValue = arrayOfInts[nextIndex]; // this won't work:
                    // non-static variable arrayOfInts cannot be referenced from a static context
                    int retValue = ds.get(nextIndex);
                    nextIndex += 2;
                    return retValue;
                }
            }
        );        
    }
}
```

Compiling this, I get:

```
error: non-static variable arrayOfInts cannot be referenced from a static context
```

The compiler complains about the access to the `arrayOfInts` variable from the anonymous class that's in the main method.

My question is: Ok I understand that I can't access a non-static variable from a static context - it completely makes sense.
But in this case, I'm not actually accessing the variable from the static context. Rather, I'm passing a piece of code - an anonymous class - to a non-static method. The non-static method can definitely access a non-static variable, so why isn't it possible?

Comment: `new DataStructure.DataStructureIterator()` should be `ds.new DataStructure.DataStructureIterator()` surely?

Comment: @user207421 Why would that help? An anonymous class created in a static context is not an inner class cannot have an enclosing instance.

Comment: OK so the next question is why is he defining an iterator in the main method at all? And if it's necessary, why not extend `EvenIterator`? Which would *require*` the `ds.` context, and provide the non-static context he needs. At the moment he is accessing things that are out of (non-static) scope.

Comment: @user207421 Yeah, I agree the design of the code is quite weird. I'd assume it's just one of those contrived scenarios to demonstrate OP's confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rather, I'm passing a piece of code - an anonymous class - to a non-static method

Java doesn't consider what you are doing with the instance that you are creating, to determine whether you can access an non-static field.

For all Java knows, you could be assigning the instance of the anonymous class to a local variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var foo = new DataStructure.DataStructureIterator() {
        public boolean hasNext() { 
            ...
        }
        public Integer next() {
            int retValue = arrayOfInts[nextIndex]; // this won't work:
            ...
        }
    };
    foo.next();
}
```

What would `foo.next()` do in this case? There is no instances of `DataStructure` anywhere!

That said, there *is* an instance of `DataStructure` in your code - `ds`. You probably meant to access the `arrayOfInts` in that instance, so just do `ds.arrayofInts` instead.

Note that the use of `arrayOfInts` inside `EvenIterator` is valid because `EvenIterator` is a inner class of `DataStructure`. Note that `DataStructureIterator`, which is also nested in `DataStructure`, is not an "inner interface". There is no such thing as "inner interfaces". `DataStructure.DataStructureIterator` is just another regular type.

To create an instance of `EvenIterator`, you need an instance of `DataStructure` first. This instance of `DataStructure` is called the *enclosing instance* of `EvenIterator`.

Because `EvenIterator` is accessing the `arrayOfInts` of its enclosing instance, and not whatever instance you are calling `print` on, this can lead to some unexpected results:

```
DataStructure ds1 = new DataStructure();
DataStructure ds2 = new DataStructure();
EvenIterator iter = ds1.new EvenIterator(); // enclosing instance is ds1
ds2.print(iter); // prints the elements of ds1, not ds2!
```

Comment: Well, that is SO feature I hate, well scored gamers do some make-ups around original authors and steal the acceptances and votes. Check the editing history of the answer

Comment: From the other side, @YoavKlein why did you accept this answer but not mine? Are you friends? Fake account of @Sweeper? Or maybe my answer is not so good and it is not even worth positive voting apart from accepting at least?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anonymous class from within the static method and trying to pass non-static field to the implementation, that is why you get the compile error. Whereas EvenIterator class is inner with regard to DataStructure so it implies to be tied to an instance of DataStructure class and can access its non-static variables.

[Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#:%7E:text=Inner%20Classes,-As%20with%20instance&text=Also%2C%20because%20an%20inner%20class,instance%20of%20the%20outer%20class.) of inner and nested classes

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields.